# JavaFX disable CSS logger

Tags: javafx

How do you disable the CSS logger in JavaFX?

There's a bug with U25 making the css logger print errors even if there is none, read more about it here:

https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issue/373/css-warnings-using-propertysheet-control

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `com.sun.javafx.Logging.getCSSLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);`?

But beware, it is not part of the public API. And I think there is a command line argument to turn off the logger, I may edit later when I find it.